# Unexpected password required at startup

Tags: password

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 plus a few additional apps.

However, I am faced with having to enter an additional password at startup, "to unlock application" wanting access to the Default keyring. 
(Please see attached screen-shot)

Is there any way to identify which app requires a password, then having done that how can I resolve the password issue?

Many thanks.
[screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l1Be.jpg)

Comment: What did you install?

Comment: Are you using an automatic login for your user (not asking for a password on startup )? If you are then this is causing the problem. Open settings - Details - Users and set "automatic login" to "off". At login, you will be asked for your password and this will unlock the keyring and you will not get this pop up again.

Comment: Can I find a way to remove the prompt and still continue to use automatic login?